# Token pasting in C not clear

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define tokenpaster(n) printf ("token" #n " = %d", token##n)

int main(void)
{
   int token34 = 40;

   tokenpaster(34);
   return 0;
}
```

[The output is](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors.htm):

```
token34 = 40
```

The author says that:

How it happened, because this example results in the following actual output from the preprocessor:

```
printf ("token34 = %d", token34);
```

How `token##n` is being converted into `token34`? Should it not be `token#34`?

Comment: "token" #n is preprocesed to "token34" - it's OK. Your question is different than your example code...

Answer (score 2):

The double-hash in a preprocessor statement glues the two arguments together. So `token##n` becomes `token##34` becomes `token34`. A single hash stringifies its argument. So `#n` becomes `"34"`. And thus the whole macro-expansion is as follows:

```
tokenparser(34);
->
printf ("token" #n " = %d", token##n);
->
printf ("token" "34" " = %d", token##34);
->
printf ("token" "34" " = %d", token34);
```

and the compiler catenates the format string, so the end-result is:

```
printf ("token34 = %d", token34);
```

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem No, the double-hash is an operator on its own, not a double-application of the single-hash operator (see C11 §6.10.3.3). If it were then it would expand to `token#"34"`, which would in turn (I guess) expand to `token "\"34\""` and result in a syntax-error.

Answer (score 0):

A single hash prefix (`#`) forces the preprocessor to [stringify](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification) your argument. Double hash prefix (`##`) simply pastes the argument and merges it with its prefix.

This means that `tokenpaster(34)` will be expanded to:

```
printf ("token" "34" " = %d", token34)
                ^^^^               ^^
                  |                 |
                  |                 +---- pasted and merged
                  |
                  +---- enclosed in quotes
```

These three string literal parts are then merged into a single literal:

```
printf ("token34 = %d", token34)
```

According to [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> §6.10.3.2 The `#` operator
>
> 2   If, in the replacement list, a parameter is immediately preceded by a `#` preprocessing
>   token, both are replaced by a **single character string literal preprocessing token** that
>   contains the spelling of the preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding
>   argument. (...)

and

> §6.10.3.3 The `##` operator
>
> 2  If, in the replacement list of a function-like macro, a parameter is immediately preceded
>   or followed by a `##` preprocessing token, the **parameter is replaced by the corresponding
>   argument's preprocessing token sequence** (...)